# Detect property change inside component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-changedetection

I am learning more about Angular and I am trying to run a method after I change a property.
This is my code

```
isLoading = false;

ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this._myService.getContent().subscribe(
        (response: IContent) => {
            this.isLoading = false;
            this.doSomething();
            // console.log(response);
        },
        err => {
            this.isLoading = false;
            this.doSomething();
            console.log(err);
        }
    );
}

doSomething() {
     console.log('some thing')
}
```

And with this I want to execute `doSomething()` after `isLoading` is set to false (like putting for example `.then(() => {this.doSomething()})` after setting). I know i can put doSomething() in timeout like

```
setTimeout(() => this.doSomething(),10);
```

and that will work but i think there is a better way. I have searched for solution and found about `ChangeDetectorRef` which i am not sure on how to implement it on this case. There also might be a different approach with which i am not familiar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case `doSomething` should be called after the `Observable` has completed. You can use the `finalize` pipe for that:

```
isLoading = false;

ngOnInit() {
  this.isLoading = true;

  this._myService.getContent().pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      this.doSomething();
    })
  ).subscribe({
    next: (response: IContent) => console.log(response),
    error: (error: any) => console.log(err)
  });
}

doSomething() {
     console.log('some thing')
}
```

---

If you -always- want to run `doSomething()` on setting `this.isLoading` to false. You can use a getter/setter:

```
get isLoading(): boolean {
  return this._isLoading;
}

set isLoading(loading: boolean) {
  this._isLoading = loading;

  if (loading) {
    this.doSomething();
  }
}

private _isLoading: boolean;
```

---

Or you can just use an extra method in your class:

```
setLoading(loading: boolean): void {
  this.loading = loading;

  if (loading) {
    this.doSomething();
  }
}
```

The last two options are frowned upon though, because the functions are no longer pure as they most likely introduce side effects

Comment: So i have to pay more attention to rxjs operators for this kinds of tasks, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please try to implement `onPush` or `ChangeDetectionStrategy` in your component

Doing this will instruct Angular to run change detection on these components and their sub-tree only when new references are passed to them versus when data is simply mutated.

Run `this.ref.markForCheck()` or `this.ref.detectChanges()` when you update your variable(or do something) and want it to reflect in html

Please check the following links for more information

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy

https://alligator.io/angular/change-detection-strategy/

Comment: OK. thank you for this answer, this will certainly come handy in other cases where i don't fetch and thus no need for rxjs, will try to do it this way also.